# Why I'm getting this error:You're accessing the development server over HTTPS, but it only supports HTTP.?

Tags: django

I'm using D`jango==3.1`, I know it is backdated but I need solution. Whenever I go to run my website I'm get this error:

```
Django version 3.1, using settings 'alef.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
[06/May/2023 00:17:02] code 400, message Bad request version ('å\x13q\x90O¢5\x98£\x02}\x8dNÅ[Di\x00\x05\x00\x03\x02h2\x00\x1b\x00\x03\x02\x00\x02\x00-\x00\x02\x01\x01\x00+\x00\x07\x06zz\x03\x04\x03\x03\x00')
[06/May/2023 00:17:02] You're accessing the development server over HTTPS, but it only supports HTTP.

[06/May/2023 00:17:02] code 400, message Bad request version ('Û\x07\x0fæ\x07¹QÔûôÛ')
[06/May/2023 00:17:02] You're accessing the development server over HTTPS, but it only supports HTTP.
```

why it coming? It is very important to fix. Can you please tell me where is the issues here? what fault I did?
this is list of requirements.txt:

```
asgiref==3.2.10
boto3==1.17.36
botocore==1.20.36
certifi==2020.12.5
chardet==4.0.0
crispy-tailwind==0.5.0
dj-database-url==0.5.0
Django==3.1
django-admin-honeypot==1.1.0
django-admin-thumbnails==0.2.5
django-crispy-forms==1.13.0
django-session-timeout==0.1.0
django-storages==1.11.1
gunicorn==20.1.0
idna==2.10
jmespath==0.10.0
Pillow==8.4.0
psycopg2-binary==2.9.5
python-dateutil==2.8.1
python-decouple==3.4
pytz==2020.1
requests==2.25.1

s3transfer==0.3.6
six==1.15.0
sqlparse==0.3.1
urllib3==1.26.3
whitenoise==5.3.0
```

Comment: Stop accessing development server using HTTPS, if you are not supporting it! Update the URL string in the browser to `http://127.0.0.1:8000` (or whatever you have there)